# Episode of a 1990's TV series (I think?) in which a gun fires color seeking darts

Tags: story-identification, tv

On one particular episode of this series, some people were asked to meet in a room. Then a person steps into the room and fires a gun at them. Then it cuts to the intro and commercial. When the show returns, the round, instead of hitting anyone that it was fired at, veers right and strikes an orange. Turns out it is a color seeking dart.

Can anyone tell me what series (or movie) that is from?

Comment: Did you actually watch this in the '90s, or is that just as estimate as to when the episode was made? Also, do you have any ideas as to what series this episode _might_ have been from?

Comment: Do you mean that it strikes a literal orange (e.g. the fruit)?